# How to sent nested response from express.js + Postgres?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I am working on a set of API, and I would like to send some response like this:

```
{
    "id":"sth",
    "names": ["", ""],
    "detail": {"": "", "": ""}
}
```

And if I just JOIN tables, the response from PG is always flat (1 layer). Is it possible to ask PG to return nested response like above, or do I have to manually call them to construct it myself with JS?

Comment: Without knowing the specific driver library you're using to access PgSQL, I would say handling it by iterating through the flat response and organize into the desired form is the most straight-forward way, and probably not that bad in terms of efficiency.

Comment: I am using this: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres library to connect to the db in heroku if that's what you are asking (sorry I'm new)

Comment: I see. I believe `node-postgres` is a very thin binding that doesn't do additional manipulation to the result set that gets returned by the database. So I would still suggest that you simply manipulate and morph the flat data structure into what you desired.